# Null pointer error in eclipse using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting Null pointer exception error in line    "wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(ElementPath)));"
in below code.

Could you please help me on this.

```
private static FluentWait<WebDriver> wait;
String  ElementPath = null;
clickAnElementByLinkText(ElementPath);
public static void clickAnElementByLinkText(String ElementPath) {        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(ElementPath)));        
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(ElementPath)).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`wait` object is null because the instance never created before used.

```
private static FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = ;
```

Instead of above line use following :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
private Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
       .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

See More https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implicit-explicit-n-fluent-wait/

Comment: What's causing the NPE in their code?

Comment: wait object is null because the instance never created before used.